Issues with Firestore Listener causing subsequent rebuilds to break until refreshed/rebooted?
Code is posted at the end as it's required to include to allow this post.
Full code here if needed: https://pastebin.com/ujX6FrKK
The main functions I believe are causing the issues are either fetchmessages, listenfornewmessages and/or the sendmessage function
I'll try explain the specifics of problem below (Flutter) - I've been building a custom chat widget integrated with Firebase to enable a real-time environment whilst also focusing on optimisation of reads via defaulting to the cache on a first basis (falling back to the network/server if needed).
Originally, this was working all really well, until I realised every time a new session would start, the Firestore Listener would query my entire chatMessages collection (I didn't spot this at first as the number of documents were low), but clearly I don't want this as it would be every app session, I'm incurring a full collection read of each conversation for users when I only want the initial fetch of 20 documents to be queried on the first instance.
As such, I modified my listener to listen for only new documents being added AFTER the timestamp of the most recent message received in the original fetch 20 documents (fetchInitialMessages function below).
If I send a message, the listener correctly identifies and appends the new message in realtime into my listview and all looks great, however if I then navigate away from that screen and then re-open up the conversation, ONLY the 'new' sent messages (ie: it ignores the 20 fetch request) appear in the list-view.
This stays this way only until I fully restart the app of which then if I go into the chat, all my messages display as I expect.

Load widget, fetch the latest 20 messages in the chatmessages collection (user can scroll up and fetch older ones if they want via the fetcholdermessages function which works nicely)

set up listener to only look at NEW documents (ie: new chat messages after the initial 20 document fetch) - the rationale here, is to avoid needing to read the entire collection and it focuses on capturing any new messages and displaying them in the listview

if user exits the chat, re-enters, it should still fetch the latest 20 messages only to begin within


Example 1:
message 1 (oldest one): Hey!
message 2: You okay?
messages 20 (latest one on widget load): I'm good thanks!
Now if the user sends a message ("OK"), as the timestamp is later/more recent than message 20's timestamp, the listener will detect it and add/update in the listview to show 21 messages
If the user now exits chat and goes back in, what I want/expect to happen is, the initial fetch occurs again and as we have 21 messages now, message 1 (hey) won't be shown, but it will fetch messages 2 - 21 and so the latest message displayed should be 'OK'
Everything works up until re-entering the chat, where in my testing, it will only show the 'OK' message and not any of the previous 19 I would expect.
Extract/relevant snippets:
class ChatListViewFirebase extends StatefulWidget {
  const ChatListViewFirebase({
    super.key,
    this.width,
    this.height,
    required this.chatId,
    required this.nameOfSender, // New input parameter
  });

final double? width;
  final double? height;
  final DocumentReference chatId;
  final String nameOfSender; // New input parameter

  @override
  State<ChatListViewFirebase> createState() => _ChatListViewFirebaseState();
}

class _ChatListViewFirebaseState extends State<ChatListViewFirebase> {
  List<Map<String, dynamic>> messages = [];
  DateTime? oldestMessageTimestamp; // Add this line to your class variables
  DateTime? latestTimestamp; // Add this line to your class variables

  bool isLoadingOlderMessages = false;
  final ScrollController _scrollController = ScrollController();
  TextEditingController messageController = TextEditingController();
  bool isSendButtonEnabled = false; // Track the send button state
  final ProfanityFilter profanityFilter =
      ProfanityFilter(); // Instantiate the ProfanityFilter

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _fetchMessages();
    _scrollController.addListener(_onScroll);

    // Add listener for text changes in the message controller
    messageController.addListener(() {
      setState(() {
        isSendButtonEnabled = messageController.text.trim().isNotEmpty;
      });
    });
  }

  Future<void> _fetchMessages() async {
    debugPrint('Fetching messages from Firebase with cache...');
    setState(() {
      messages.clear();
    });
    await _fetchInitialMessages();
    _listenForNewMessages();
  }

  void _listenForNewMessages() {
    debugPrint('Listening for new messages...');
    widget.chatId
        .collection('chatMessages')
        .where('timeStamp',
            isGreaterThan: latestTimestamp) // Only listen for new messages
        .orderBy('timeStamp', descending: true)
        .snapshots()
        .listen((snapshot) {
      for (var change in snapshot.docChanges) {
        final newMessage = {
          'message': change.doc['message'],
          'timeStamp': change.doc['timeStamp'],
          'uidOfSender': change.doc['uidOfSender'],
          'nameOfSender': change.doc['nameOfSender'] ?? widget.nameOfSender,
        };

        if (change.type == DocumentChangeType.added) {
          // Check if the new message's timestamp is older than the oldest fetched message
          if (oldestMessageTimestamp != null &&
              (newMessage['timeStamp'] as Timestamp)
                  .toDate()
                  .isBefore(oldestMessageTimestamp!)) {
            debugPrint('Ignoring old message: $newMessage');
            continue; // Skip this message
          }

          if (!messages
              .any((msg) => msg['timeStamp'] == newMessage['timeStamp'])) {
            setState(() {
              messages.insert(0, newMessage);
              debugPrint('New message received: $newMessage');
            });
          }
        } else if (change.type == DocumentChangeType.modified) {
          setState(() {
            final index = messages.indexWhere(
                (msg) => msg['timeStamp'] == newMessage['timeStamp']);
            if (index != -1) {
              messages[index] = newMessage;
              debugPrint('Message modified: $newMessage');
            }
          });
        } else if (change.type == DocumentChangeType.removed) {
          setState(() {
            messages.removeWhere(
                (msg) => msg['timeStamp'] == newMessage['timeStamp']);
            debugPrint('Message deleted: $newMessage');
          });
        }
      }
    });
  }

  Future<void> _fetchInitialMessages() async {
    debugPrint('Fetching initial messages from Firebase...');
    QuerySnapshot snapshot = await widget.chatId
        .collection('chatMessages')
        .orderBy('timeStamp',
            descending: true) // Ensure you are ordering by timestamp
        .limit(20)
        .get(const GetOptions(source: Source.cache));

    if (snapshot.docs.isEmpty) {
      snapshot = await widget.chatId
          .collection('chatMessages')
          .orderBy('timeStamp',
              descending: true) // Ensure you are ordering by timestamp
          .limit(20)
          .get(const GetOptions(source: Source.server));
    }

    final List<Map<String, dynamic>> newMessages = snapshot.docs.map((doc) {
      return {
        'message': doc['message'],
        'timeStamp': doc['timeStamp'],
        'uidOfSender': doc['uidOfSender'],
        'nameOfSender': doc['nameOfSender'] ??
            widget.nameOfSender, // Default to input if null
      };
    }).toList();

    // Set the oldest message timestamp
    if (newMessages.isNotEmpty) {
      oldestMessageTimestamp = newMessages.last['timeStamp']
          .toDate(); // Assuming timeStamp is a Timestamp
    }

    print("Oldest message timestamp: $oldestMessageTimestamp");

    // Set the latest message timestamp
    if (newMessages.isNotEmpty) {
      latestTimestamp =
          newMessages.first['timeStamp'].toDate(); // Store latest timestamp
    }

    debugPrint("Latest message timestamp: $latestTimestamp");

    setState(() {
      messages = newMessages;
      debugPrint('Initial messages loaded: $messages');
    });
  }

  Future<void> _sendMessage(String messageText) async {
    if (messageText.trim().isEmpty) return;

    // Check for profanity
    if (profanityFilter.hasProfanity(messageText)) {
      _showProfanityAlert();
      return; // Stop the process if profanity is detected
    }

    // Get the current user's UID
    final currentUser = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
    if (currentUser == null) {
      debugPrint('Error: No user is currently logged in.');
      return;
    }

    final newMessageData = {
      'message': messageText,
      'timeStamp': FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
      'uidOfSender': currentUser.uid, // Use the current user's UID
      'nameOfSender': widget.nameOfSender, // Use input name for sender
    };

    // Add message to Firestore
    await widget.chatId.collection('chatMessages').add(newMessageData);

    // Update parent document with latest message info
    await widget.chatId.update({
      'lastMessage': messageText,
      'lastMessageTimeStamp': FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
    });

    // Immediately display the new message with a temporary timestamp
    setState(() {
      messages.insert(0, {
        ...newMessageData,
        'timeStamp': DateTime.now(), // Set to now temporarily
      });
    });

    messageController.clear();
    debugPrint('Message sent: $newMessageData');
  }

 
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        Expanded(
          child: Stack(
            children: [
              ListView.builder(
                controller: _scrollController,
                itemCount: messages.length,
                reverse: true, // Add this line
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  final message = messages[index];
                  final isSentByMe = message['uidOfSender'] ==
                      FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser?.uid;
               
  String _formatTimestamp(dynamic timestamp) {
    if (timestamp == null) return '';
    final DateTime dateTime =
        (timestamp is DateTime) ? timestamp : (timestamp as Timestamp).toDate();
    return '${dateTime.hour}:${dateTime.minute.toString().padLeft(2, '0')}'; // Formatting to "HH:mm"
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    messageController.dispose();
    _scrollController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }
}



